# Dynamic field access in Haskell

Tags: haskell, coordinate-system

I have to transform a response into the internal Coordinate record, some of the fields are lists and I need to handle empty lists case.

**Records:**

```
newtype GeoResponse =
  GeoResponse
    { results :: [ResultResponse]
    }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

newtype ResultResponse =
  ResultResponse
    { locations :: [LocationResponse]
    }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

newtype LocationResponse =
  LocationResponse
    { latLng :: CoordinateResponse
    }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)

data CoordinateResponse =
  CoordinateResponse
    { lat :: !Double
    , lng :: !Double
    }
  deriving (Eq, Show, Generic)
```

**Mapper function:**

```
toCoordinate :: GeoResponse -> Coordinate
toCoordinate (GeoResponse (ResultResponse [LocationResponse (CoordinateResponse lat lng)]:_)) =
  Coordinate lat lng
toCoordinate _ = Coordinate 0 0
```

So I didn't find a better way to get Coordinate without pattern match, but it looks a bit ugly to me.

Do you have any suggestion to improve my code?

Answer (score 2):

Note that, if you just remove the tag `Response` from all your types (including unifying the types `CoordinateResponse` and `Coordinate` which seem like they ought to be a single type), it's already a lot more readable:

```
toCoordinate :: Geo -> Coordinate
toCoordinate (Geo (Result [Location coord]:_)) = coord
toCoordinate _ = Coordinate 0 0
```

Also, the `Location` newtype doesn't seem to be serving any purpose, so maybe `Location` and `Coordinate` should just be the same type, too, which would remove a level.

Otherwise, what you've written is pretty idiomatic.  It's possible to use `coerce` to "cut through" all of the newtypes, so you could write:

```
import Data.Coerce

toCoordinate' :: GeoResponse -> Coordinate
toCoordinate' gr = case coerce gr of
  [CoordinateResponse lat lng]:_ -> Coordinate lat lng
  _                              -> Coordinate 0 0
```

or if `CoordinateResponse` and `Coordinate` were the same type:

```
toCoordinate' :: Geo -> Coordinate
toCoordinate' gr = case coerce gr of
  [coord]:_ -> coord
  _         -> Coordinate 0 0
```

That's obviously shorter, though it may hide what you're doing.  It seems important that you are pattern matching against the first of (possibly many) `ResultResponse` values but requiring that response to consist of a single `LocationResponse`, and that's not so obvious from this version.